# Whats a good rate of change in frames for starting out in animation with adobe animate?

Tags: animation, image-editing, adobe-animate

I am starting out drawing some basic animations in adobe animate. what I am wondering is
what is recommended for drawing changes in the animation like how many frames in between should I skip to achieve something that doesn't zoom past too fast. to more refine what I am trying to ask
How would I go about drawing a simple talking face that don't seem to be choppy or too fast in the progression. I might be answering it myself a little here but I was thinking like every 15 frames draw something changed. Sorry if this has been asked a bunch of times before I am looking for an updated response on what works best for you that you recommend for me.

Comment: The idea is you set your fps [frames per second] first, then you don't need to skip any at all. 12-16 fps seems a commonly-accepted lowest rate.

Comment: thanks this was helpful advice as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common one I believe is using 24 fps and drawing on 1s 2s or 3s depending on the speed of the object/character. Meaning if you draw a snail and a rabbit you may want to change every frame for the rabbit and every third one for the snail...
But if you get started it is probably easiest, as suggested, to lower the framerate to 8 or so and draw every frame.

Comment: thank you this is great advice